# How can I write in a different dataframe the initial and final date when a string changes?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, time-series

I'm new to Python and I'm having some trouble writing the following in a pythonic way and not using too many loops that could slow down the performance.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Datetime    Status    Value  
2014-09-28 18:00:00    On    3  
2014-09-28 19:00:00    On    3  
2014-09-28 20:00:00    On    3  
2014-09-28 21:00:00    Off    4  
2014-09-28 22:00:00    Off    6  
2014-09-28 23:00:00    Unknown  nan  
2014-09-29 00:00:00    Unknown  nan  
2014-09-29 01:00:00    Unknown  nan  
2014-09-29 02:00:00    Unknown  nan  
2014-09-29 03:00:00    On    1  
2014-09-29 04:00:00    On    3  
2014-09-29 05:00:00    On    5  
2014-09-29 06:00:00    Off    3  
2014-09-29 07:00:00    Off    2
```

And I need to create another dataframe with the initial, final date and duration the machine was in a certain status. In addition, I would like to determine the average value for each status (consecutive lines with same status). For example:

```
Initial_date         Final_date           Duration  Value Status     
2014-09-28 18:00:00  2014-09-28 20:00:00  3         3    On      
2014-09-28 21:00:00  2014-09-28 22:00:00  2         5    Off    
2014-09-28 23:00:00  2014-09-29 02:00:00  4         nan    Unknown  
2014-09-29 03:00:00  2014-09-29 05:00:00  3         3     On  
2014-09-29 06:00:00  2014-09-29 07:00:00  2         2.5    Off
```

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, Can you explain with more detail how the initial and final dates are chosen? What are you pivoting the Data on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to construct your dataframe using something like this:

```
idx = df[df.ne(df.shift(-1)).Status].index
idx2 = pd.cut(df.index, bins=np.append([0], idx), 
                  include_lowest=True, right=True)

df2=pd.DataFrame({
        'Initial_date':df[df.ne(df.shift()).Status].Datetime.values,
        'Final_date':df[df.ne(df.shift(-1)).Status].Datetime.values,
        'Duration':df.groupby(idx2, as_index=False).size().values,
        'Value':df.groupby(idx2, as_index=False).Value.mean().values.flatten(),
        'Status':df.groupby(idx2, as_index=False).Status.first().values.flatten()
        })
```

In this script I identify when the variable 'Status' is changing by comparing it with a shifted version of the same dataframe. This is done by combining pandas [eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html?highlight=eq#pandas.DataFrame.eq) and [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html?highlight=shift) functions. Data are then segmented using pandas [cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html?highlight=pandas%20cut#pandas.cut) and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) functions to obtain the aggregate statistics that  you requested (duration, mean value and status). This can easily be extended to obtain other meaningful quantities if you like (*e.g.* standard deviation).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works very well! :)  I just added the column name when determining the mean value:   'Value':df.groupby(idx2, as_index=False).Value.mean().values.flatten()

Comment: yes you are right, I missed that typo. Now I've edited the answer. I'm glad it helped you.